# Find minimum of single-variable function

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab question:

What expression is calculated by the following command in Matlab?
Code:
`fminbnd(@(x) (sin(x).^2-1),0,pi)`
Minimum of:
(a) f(x)=1-sin x^2 or (b)1-sin^2x.

I am not really sure. I have pluged the x values into both of my options and the one that returns the matching y value is the correct function. BUt for both equations i get 1, so i don't know what is right a) or b)?

Answer (score 0):

Function evaluations have higher precedence than raising to a power. So

```
sin(x).^2-1
```

is the same as

```
(sin(x)).^2-1
```

I.e., you do the sin(x) first, then square this result.
Which is not the same as

```
sin(x.^2)-1
```